# When is it useful to write an r.v. $Y$ as $f(X)$ where $f$ is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Suppose $X$ is a random variable on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. Let $\sigma(X)$ denote the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on which $X$ is measurable and suppose $Y$ is a $\sigma(X)$-measurable random variable. It can be shown that there exists a measurable function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $$Y = f(X).$$

What are some examples of where this result is useful? It kind of looks like a change of variables but I’m not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Often in statistics one encounters a sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ of independent identically distributed random variables and one is concerned with the sample mean $\overline X = (X_1+\cdots+X_n)/n$ and the sample variance $S^2 = \big( (X_1-\overline X)^2 + \cdots + (X_n-\overline X\,)^2\big)/(n-1).$

The pair $\big(\overline X , S^2\big) $ is a measurable function of the $n$-tuple $(X_1,\ldots,X_n).$

Understanding the distribution of $S^2$ above when $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are normally distributed begins with understanding the distribution of $Z^2$ where $Z\sim\operatorname N(0,1).$

The "characteristic function" $\chi$ of a probability distribution is a sort of Fourier transform defined by
$$
\chi(t) = \operatorname E(e^{itX})
$$
where $X$ is a random variable with the distribution in question.

Maybe I'll add more examples here later.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It looks like you’ve given some examples of a random variable which is defined as a (measurable) function of another random variable. I am asking for a related, but different example: where we start with two random variables $Y$ and $X$, and apply the theorem above to obtain a measurable function $f$ such that $Y = f(X)$.